# Unable to upload file into folder

Tags: php, html

I'm unable to upload files into the folder.

```
URL = 'http://localhost/ezy_mvc/';

$newFilePath = URL."public/uploads";

I tried using relative url instead of http:// like = ../../public/uploads
```

Data structure:
[image]

I'm using MVC framework. Therefore I have controller, model and view.

controller:

```
 function upload()
        {
            $this->model->upload();
        }
```

Model:

```
function upload()
    {
        // Count # of uploaded files in array
        $total = count($_FILES['files']['name']);

        // Loop through each file
        for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
        //Get the temp file path
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];

        //Make sure we have a filepath
        if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
        //Setup our new file path
        //$newFilePath = "./uploadFiles/" . $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
        $newFilePath = URL."public/uploads";
        //Upload the file into the temp dir
        move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath);
        /*if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
        //Handle other code here
        }*/
        }
       }
    }
```

Error ( Warning ):

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(http://localhost/ezy_mvc/public/uploads): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in C:\wamp\www\ezy_mvc\models\product_model.php on line 24

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php50B6.tmp' to 'http://localhost/ezy_mvc/public/uploads' in C:\wamp\www\ezy_mvc\models\product_model.php on line 24
```

Comment: @Saty, how's the absolute path looks like

Comment: `/var/www/ezy_mvc/public/uploads` like this

Comment: make sure that path is working

Comment: Your url should be path from root not this  'http://localhost/ezy_mvc/';

Comment: @Saty, I tried this: C:/wamp/www/ezy_mvc/public/uploads but it saysThe second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory

Comment: l guess the path must be like this.`$path="C:/........../public/uploads";
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"], $path);`

Comment: @Hachachin, is my path in above comment correct?

Comment: use the full path.

Comment: @Hachachin, I've no idea which is full path?

Comment: lets say you are using xampp, path is as example  $path="C:/xampp/htdocs/ezy_mvc/public/uploads";

Comment: @Hachachin, I'm using wamp, so I think this is my path: C:/wamp/www/ezy_mvc/public/uploads   BUT this one also emits error

Comment: the same error/warning as above?

Comment: @Hachachin, problem solved...you're answer is right ..I need to use absolute path. I missed the file name..So the correct one will be this: C:/wamp/www/ezy_mvc/public/uploads". $_FILES['files']['name'][$i]